# Format Timespan greater than 24 hours

Tags: javascript

I have an application which displays the amount of work somebody has done on a specific topic.

There I am receiving a `timespan` which I wan't to format in **hours**. When trying to format the `timespan` using `Date` it returns `NaN`, because a day can't have more than 24 hours.

---

received timespan: `{6.20:37:30.9980000}`

desired output (hh:mm:ss): `32:50:37`

```
    function timeToday() {
        var url = "@Url.Action("CalcTimeToday")";
        $.get(url, function (time) {
            var totalTime = new Date("0001/01/01 " + time);
            var h = format(totalTime.getHours(), 2);
            var m = format(totalTime.getMinutes(), 2);
            var s = format(totalTime.getSeconds(), 2);
            totalTime = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            $('#timeToday').html(totalTime);
        })
    };
```

Comment: You mean the time should be in `hh:mm:ss` format no matter how big the time is?

Comment: Yea, that's an even better solution.

Comment: Can you share the format of `time` that you are receiving?

Answer (score -1):

As in the problem stated, it's not possible to format a `timespan` greater than 24 hours when using `Date`, as a day does not have more than 24 hours.

I now instead format the `timespan` to seconds and then calculate the time using `Math.floor`.

```
function timeToday() {
    var url = "@Url.Action("CalcTimeToday")";
    $.get(url, function (seconds) {
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600).toLocaleString('de-CH', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false });
        seconds %= 3600;
        var minutes = ("0" + Math.floor(seconds / 60)).slice(-2);
        seconds = ("0" + (seconds % 60)).slice(-2);
        var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        
        $('#timeToday').html(time);
        })
    };
```

Comment: Where is `s` comming from?